# wine in Xmonad is not tiling

Tags: wine, xmonad

I'm using `Wine` application in `Xmonad`. But it is not tiling like other applications. Can this be configured, that `Wine` will tile like
other applications?

Answer (score 0):

You're not giving me a whole lot to work with (no details about your wine setup) but maybe the following will help: Run winecfg, switch to the graphics tab and tell it to emulate a virtual desktop (choose an appropriate size). Afterwards, everything should tile nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Wine programs default to floating, but using `super-t` (or whatever key binding you use for turning on tiling) will make them tile just fine.  Is that your issue?